# When calling a WCF channel from multiple threads some threads might get stuck for a long time

Tags: multithreading, wcf, c#-4.0

I have encountered a weird problem in one of my projects. I am creating one WCF channel and trying to consume it from multiple threads. The service I am targeting is shut down so I except to get an exception after the "Open timeout" (30 seconds in my case) at most. But what I have seen is that the first two calls to the channel are finished (with exception) really quickly. all the other calls are finished after 20 minutes (My receive timeout).

I am using the same channel because I don't want to wait for the channel to open for each request (Can take a few seconds in case of security and high latency). I have read that a channel is thread safe so I didn't think it should be a problem.

I am using dot net 4

Code sample:

```
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:9000/SomeService");
var netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();

var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(netTcpBinding, address);

IService channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

Parallel.For(0, 10, new ParallelOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10}, i =>
{
    try
    {
        channel.SomeOperation();
    }
    catch
    {

    }
});
```

I have tried to Close/Abort/Dispose the channel in the catch block but it didn't help.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe it was this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568158/concurrent-wcf-calls-via-shared-channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find a standard solution but what I did find is that when I use async calls the problem doesn't happen (tested it several time with a 100 iterations loop.

```
Parallel.For(0, 10, new ParallelOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10}, i =>
{
     try
    {
        var result = channel.BeginSomeOperation();
        channel.EndSomeOperation(result);
    }
    catch
    {

    }
});
```

Comment: This is just evil. Using the Threadpool with ASP.Net. This is going to kill your scalability.

Comment: If you are referring to the parallel loop. It's just for testing purposes.

And, I am not using ASP.Net.

Answer (score 3):

A Channel only has one connection, so even if it is thread-safe, you won't get the asynchronous benefits of using Parallel. Create a channel per loop and ensure that you close the channel after each request or you'll exhaust the connection pool on your machine from undisposed connections retained by the Channel.

Comment: But if I will open many channels I will have to wait till the channel will open which as I said is a long operation in some cases.

Comment: Yes you will.  That's the penalty of wanting to have multiple connections at the same time.  You can't have something for nothing.

Comment: If I will hold only one channel I won't get this penalty (except for once when opening the connection. The only thing that stops me is the problem I described.

Comment: You're missing the point that if there's only one connection, the parallelism is pointless as the requests will serialized into running one-by-one.

Do you get the same problem if you just run the code in a standard for loop?

Comment: Been a long time but still... No I don't have the problem when using standard for. And I am not doing the parallelism to gain some performance benefit. Just that several places in my code can call the same proxy from different thread and I don't want them to get stuck in case the connection is faulted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
var tasks = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
            select TaskEx.FromAsync(channel.BeginSomeOperation, channel.EndSomeOperation, null);
var results = from t in TaskEx.WhenAll(tasks)
              select t.Result;
```

PS TaskEx is in the Async targeting pack.